# angular-cli: using systemjs path maps

Tags: angular, typescript, webpack, angular-cli

I am aware that **[angular-cli](https://cli.angular.io/)** uses webpack as its base, but I am also trying to use a plugin that requires systemjs map paths.

The plugin is called **[ang2-parallax](https://github.com/allenRoyston/ang2-parallax)** , and it requires these systemjs settings:

```
var map = {
    'app':                        'app', // 'dist',
    '@angular':                   'node_modules/@angular',
    'angular2-in-memory-web-api': 'node_modules/angular2-in-memory-web-api',
    'rxjs':                       'node_modules/rxjs',
    'NG2_parallax':               'node_modules/ang2-parallax'
};

var packages = {
    'app':                        { main: 'main.js',  defaultExtension: 'js' },
    'rxjs':                       { defaultExtension: 'js' },
    'angular2-in-memory-web-api': { main: 'index.js', defaultExtension: 'js' },
    'NG2_parallax':               { defaultExtension: 'js' }
};
```

Is it possible to implement the plugin using angular-cli (webpack)?

Answer (score 0):

Yeah that should work fine. SystemJS uses explicit configuration to determine the location of your app and its dependencies. Webpack primarily defers to NodeJS's resolution algorithm which tries as hard as it possibly can to find something with the requested name somewhere, walking all the way up the directory tree and recursing into subdirectories of node modules before giving up. Personally I think this behavior is crazy but that's what it does.